# Drupal 7: Adding weight to drupal_add_js isn't changing position of script

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a whole bunch of modules that add .js scripts to the head using `drupal_add_js`. I want to make sure one of the scripts appears above all others. To that affect I have added a `weight` value to the options:

```
drupal_add_js(some_GTM_script.js, 
 array(
    'type' => 'inline',
    'scope' => 'head_scripts',
    'weight' => 99,
 ));
```

But nothing changes. I've tried `99`, `-99`, `0`, `10`, but not matter what the script's position doesn't change.

Would anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative weight within the proper `scope` and `group`.

> **weight**: A number defining the order in which the JavaScript is added to the page relative to other JavaScript *with the same '**scope**', '**group**' and 'every_page' value.*
>
> **group**: a number identifying the group in which to add the JavaScript. Available constants are :
>
> - JS_LIBRARY: Any libraries, settings, or jQuery plugins.
> - JS_DEFAULT: Any module-layer JavaScript.
> - JS_THEME: Any theme-layer JavaScript.
>
> The group number serves as a weight: JavaScript within a lower weight group is presented on the page before JavaScript within a higher weight group.

So, if '*head_scripts*' is the first region to appear on the page, you still have to define the script '*group*', ie. library scripts appear before theme scripts.

To enforce the priority of your script you may need to use `JS_DEFAULT - x`, or even `JS_LIBRARY - x` if you want it to be included before anything, even jQuery etc.

```
drupal_add_js(some_GTM_script.js, 
 array(
    'type' => 'inline',
    'scope' => 'head_scripts',
    'group' => JS_LIBRARY - 1
    'weight' => -99,
 ));
```